# Develop generic JMS messaging framework code

Tags: java, jms

I need to develop JMS based application which will asynchronously process inbound and outbound messages with third party systems.

Is it possible to develop generic JMS application which at runtime may use MQSeriers or WebLogic JMS? any examples of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a App server agnostic Message System, you can try something line HornetMQ, RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ and check how you can use them from your application (these MQ's can be configured apart from any application server) or you can check how you can integrate them with a specific server.